# replaceing default header/footer with custom template part in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, gutenberg-blocks

the code below is part of main php code for Dokan Vendor Shop Page.

in Full Site Editing i have added my custom header / footer (name in template part: My Custom Header) and using `replace option`i was able to show them instead of default header/footer in all other template but i am unble to replace/show them in this custom php code.

i have tried `get_header( 'my_custom_header' );` and  `php get_footer( 'my_custom_footer' );` and no luck.

please help me how to achieve that?

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 * @package dokan - 2014 1.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}
get_header( 'shop' );
?>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' ); ?>
<div class="dokan-store-wrap 
....
....
</div><!-- .dokan-store-wrap -->
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' ); ?>
<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing two meanings of template. `get_header()` is [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/) (and the same `get_footer()`) which will "paste" the code of a php file. So your theme has a *.php template (in your case it will be named `header-shop.php`) and by calling `get_header()` it will add header in process of rendering the website.

On the other hand, you created your header/footer templates in Gutenberg editor. They are handled by a Gutenberg plugin. You should just try `call get_header();` without any parameters. It should be handled in the standard way and then you can modify it using Full Site Editing.

Before that, you should check if on your specific page there isn't a function `get_header()` override. It can be done by some plugin.